# SQL Grab Data from most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to write a query that will grab the most recent retail from the most recent date.
My data from the inner query looks like this:

```
Packnum  Mail Date      Retail
600002   2018-07-01     20.99
600002   2020-09-20     24.99
600003   2020-01-06     31.99
600003   2019-01-01     26.99
```

I'm trying to get the highest mail date and the retail that goes with it.
For example I want to only see:

```
Packnum  Mail Date      Retail
600002   2020-09-20     24.99
600003   2020-01-06     31.99
```

My current code is as follows: (I know I have sloppy coding I'm still learning and no expert)

```
SELECT 
a.packnum
,r.Retail as [Current Retail]
,MAX(b.firstreleasemailed) as Maildate

FROM pic704current a JOIN CatCov b on (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear)
JOIN

(SELECT DISTINCT a.packnum  ,max(b.FirstReleaseMailed) as Maildate ,a.RetOne as Retail
FROM PIC704Current a JOIN CatCov b on (a.CatID = b.Offer) and (a.Year = b.MailYear) 
WHERE 
b.firstreleasemailed <= getdate()
GROUP BY a.PackNum, a.RetOne
)r
ON a.RetOne = r.Retail  
WHERE 
(a.DiscountReasonCode Not in ('LT','UP', 'OR', 'ER', 'IP'))
and b.firstreleasemailed <= getdate()

GROUP BY a.packnum ,r.Retail
order by PackNum
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

On your main query you can apply CTE like below and get the desirec result:

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/90620/1)

```
WITH CTE1 AS
(SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Packnum ORDER BY [Mail Date] DESC) RN
 FROM TABLE1 A)
 SELECT * FROM CTE1 WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm still working out exactly what you did. I'm not as familiar creating temp tables etc... (still learning) but I'm working with what you gave me to try to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Let me know if you need any help at any stage.